# Old version controller to GIT content migration using Windows batch file

Tags: git, batch-file

I am migrating the content from old VC to GIT , have written simple windows batch file to checkout the files from old VC and check in to GIT repo.This works fine , however I want to check if any file is deleted from old VC , how to detect it and delete it from GIT also.using batch script.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why this question should even come up...  If your procedure follows the steps below, it should be automatic.

If you have a procedure for properly checking out the version from the old system, then any file deleted from version control will be deleted from the filesystem when you check out that version.

(I suppose if for some reason that isn't happening - perhaps due to a defect of the version control system - you could clear the working tree completely between checkouts.  Just be careful not to destroy the `.git/` directory.)

One way or other, once you have a correct working copy of the next version (which includes the file having been deleted), you next would update the index.  The simplest way to do this is, in the root directory of the working tree:

```
git add .
```

If you're doing that, then the index is updated to reflect *exactly* what's in the working tree - which means deletes are being reflected.  (If you're not doing that - perhaps you instead take directory listings and individually `add` files, which would indeed miss deletes - then why?)

And then you simply run `git commit`.

Comment: Thank @Mark , let me rephrase it again.I have migrated one project from Old VC to git, in case some user delete one file from old VC and I want that file to be deleted from GIT also.in manual case this is piece of cake but I am doing all this through batch script.so while check out from Old VC to file system to check-in to GIT it should ignore the deleted file.I need to add that piece of script.Hope you got my point.